# Easy-Pdf not working with JavaScript updated page

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, pdf

Easypdf django isn't rendering the dynamic content of a html page, but working fine with static content.

Here is the code I referenced to produce the pdf

```
from easy_pdf.views import PDFTemplateView

class HelloPDFView(PDFTemplateView):
 template_name = "hello.html"
  def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
   return super(HelloPDFView, self).get_context_data(
    pagesize="A4",
    title="Hi there!",
    **kwargs
 )
```